# how utf-8 identifies the different language character

Tags: html, utf-8

I am really amazed to see the magic of utf-8 but couldn't understand the logic behind it. I went through several documents but still confused though i know the basic only.

please take a look [first example](http://jsfiddle.net/XfTaB/6/). it converts `from language character to utf-8`. there are two text box, in first text box enter the chars, click the button and get the `utf-8` values in second text box as `utf-8`.

please take a look of the [second example](http://jsfiddle.net/NWGu8/1/) . i have used the `utf-8 char from the example 1 and put the value in html` and here i really do not understand how it translates. as i tested three language `chinese, Hindi and Russian`.

```
used google translator to translate from english to several language
Hello = 您好(chinese)

Hello = नमस्ते (Hindi)

Hello = привет (Russian)
```

how does a web page identify the language character on the basis of `utf-8` ? is it possible that different computer will show different character ?

Answer (score 2):

The "magic" behind UTF-8 is called [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). It is one of several encodings of the standard.

Unicode does have character ranges that correspond to languages and many characters are specifically associated with a language.

I suggest reading this - [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Thanks Oded ! i hope it should help to enhance my understanding level.

Comment: To expand on this, those characters are different characters, you store the pointers to those characters. Unicode has nothing to do with translation :-)

Comment: @ikanobori: what do you mean by pointers ?? does it mean that unicode chararcter is already defined and stored somewhere ??

Comment: Each character in the unicode standard is stored with a specific number, see these: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode) an encoding (like utf-8) is a way to represent those numbers with bytes.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 is a variable-length byte encoding of Unicode, the character numbering system for all languages.

Internet web pages by default base on ISO-8859-1, so called Latin-1. Other charsets can be set by:

1. Header lines of text, preceding an empty line and then the HTML content text.
   There a header line:

   ```
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
   ```

   A Java EE server needs to do for this:

   ```
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
   ```
2. In the HTML head a meta tag

   ```
   <html>
     <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
   ...
   ```

Comment: Websites don't by "default" base on ISO-8859-1. You'll find out that most browsers default to UTF-8 (or the encoding of the current locale of the logged in user) if they can't determine the encoding with their encoding detection (which is always hard to do and often fails).

Comment: Yes the default encoding can be set in the browser (I did too). Web servers application defaults still stem from the obsolete US dominated internet. One won't find old American pages where Latin-1 was explicitly set.

Comment: One change, 8859 is an encoding made for European script (ASCII was the previous 128 characters and the other 127 are filled with accented letters). The first 128 characters' bytes are the same in virtually every encoding for compatibility.